# Best way to encapsulate chucks of html inside directives with injected attributes

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <a e-form="review_link" ng-click="review_link.$show()" editable-text="post.review_link" buttons="no" blur="submit" e-placeholder="Leave blank to use default value">{{ post.url }}</a>
  <a e-form="title" ng-click="title.$show()" editable-text="post.title" buttons="no" blur="submit" e-placeholder="Leave blank to use default value">{{ post.title }}</a>
  <a e-form="author" ng-click="author.$show()" editable-text="post.author" buttons="no" blur="submit" e-placeholder="Leave blank to use default value">{{ post.author }}</a>
  <!-- other different widgets -->
</div>
```

I was trying to do something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <custom-directive field="field" ng-repeat="field in ['review_link', 'title', 'author']"></custom-directive>
  <!-- other different widgets -->
</div>
```

and on directive:

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      field: '='
    },
    template: '<a e-form="{{field}}" ng-click="{{field}}.$show()" editable-text="post[{{field}}]" buttons="no" blur="submit" e-placeholder="Leave blank to use default value">{{ post.author }}</a>' 
  }
}
```

but I got compile syntax errors

PD: I'm using http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#overview at the example.

Comment: Basically, syntax error means there's something wrong with the syntax (colons, braces, parentheses, commas, keywords, tokens order)... Posting a specific error message could be helpful to track down your very problem.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax error caused by `ng-click="{{field}}.$show()"`.

change it to
`ng-click="field.$show()"`. you don't need curly braces inside `ng-repeat`

**In addition,** it seems you are trying to access `post` from your directive's template (which is not gonna work because it's not shared with the directive - the scope is isolated).

what to do? add `post` to `scope` like this:

```
scope: {
  field: '=',
  post: '='
},
```

add pass it to your directive just as you did with `field`:

```
<custom-directive field="field" post="post" ...
```

### example: http://plnkr.co/edit/szDjDw3bnLtDSRr2O08H?p=preview